# How to block IPs on google adwords with python api

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have everything set up on my google adwords account and I'm able to retrieve data via the API. However, I just can't seem to find how I'm supposed to add IP addresses to the blacklist

I know that I should be using IPBlock, I just don't know how

I found an old code that goes like this:

```
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

client = (GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path="google-ads.yaml"))
campaign_criterion_operation = client.get_type('CampaignCriterionOperation', version='v2')
campaign_criterion = campaign_criterion_operation.create
campaign_criterion.negative.value = True
campaign_criterion.campaign.value = campaign_service.campaign_path(customer, campaign)
campaign_criterion.ip_block.ip_address.value = "80.67.167.81"
campaign_criterion_response = campaign_criterion_service.mutate_campaign_criteria(customer, [campaign_criterion_operation])

for reponse in campaign_criterion_response.results:
    print('Added campaign criterion "%s".' % reponse.resource_name)
```

However, it has multiple issues if you try to run it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `However, it has multiple issues if you try to run it.` Can you be more specific? What goes wrong?

Comment: Apart from having to change from version v2 to any from v8-v10, it also says that there's no attribute 'value' for 'campaign_criterion.negative.value', and 'campaign_service' is not defined